# How do I properly create a function that returns a list of custom object type objects?

Tags: java

I am having problems with defining a function for solving a cubic equation. The problem is it needs to return a list of complex numbers as the result.

*(cubic_cardano.java)*

```
package oop;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class cubic_cardano {
    public static List<Complex> solveCubic(Сomplex a, Сomplex b, Сomplex c, Сomplex d){
        List<Complex> output = new ArrayList<>();
        ...
    }
...
```

*(Complex.java)*

```
package oop;

public class Сomplex {
    private double re;
    private double im;

    public Сomplex(double real, double imag) {
        re = real;
        im = imag;
    }
...
```

For some reason, I am getting a **Complex cannot be resolved to a type** error for each line with the *List<Complex>* expression in it. What could be the reason?

Comment: Run with an IDE which will resolve all classes for you. Don't run with cmd. In an IDE I don't there would be any problem, if they are in the same package. (Oh you don't define the package in the beginning of the class file, do you?)

Comment: @WesternGun I did define the package in each file, sorry, forgot to include that in the snippet. Trying another IDE was my initial thought as well, guess I will just try that

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Can you please add the package to the snippets? Thanks.

Comment: @JoãoDias I am using vscode. Made an edit to the post to include the expression I use to define the package (both files are in a folder called _oop_)

Comment: Then it should work without the need for an import statement. Try IntelliJ or some other IDE. I am not used to vscode.